# Unset a specific variable within a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I can't figure out how do this at all.  My first attempt involved using references and calling unset on a reference simply unlinks the reference.  I tried recursion but couldn't get it to work, I then tried array_walk and array_filter without success.  Here is a simple example that demonstrates what I am trying to do.

```
<?
class Sample {
    //Please note this can have a completely variable amount of vars/dimensions
    $data = array("system" => array("value1","value2"), "session" => array("value1"));

    public function erase($value){
         //Here I am suppose to somehow delete that exists in $this->data
    }
    public function display(){
         print_r($this->data);
    }
 }


 $Sample = new Sample();
 $Sample->erase(array("system","value1"));
 //I am extremely flexible on the format of the erase parameter ($value)
 $Sample->display();

 should output with the variable unset($this->data["system"]["value1"]) :

 array("system" => array("value2"), "session" => array("value1")
```

Ohgodwhy helped by creating a [eval.in with a slighly modified example](https://eval.in/197702)

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I've made this function and work pretty great**.

```
function erase(array &$arr, array $children)
{
    $ref = &$arr;
    foreach ($children as $child)
        if (is_array($ref) && array_key_exists($child, $ref)) {
            $toUnset = &$ref;
            $ref = &$ref[$child];
        } else
            throw new Exception('Path does\'nt exist');
    unset($toUnset[end($children)]);
}
```

---

**Example 1**:

Here's an example of how you would unset `$arr['session']['session3']['nestedSession2']`

```
$arr = [
    "system" => [
        "system1" => "value1",
        "system2" => "value2"
    ],
    "session" => [
        "session1" => "value3",
        "session2" => "value4",
        "session3" => [
            "nestedSession1" => "value5",
            "nestedSession2" => "value6",
        ],
    ],
];

print_r($arr);
erase($arr, array('session', 'session3', 'nestedSession2'));
print_r($arr);
```

---

**Example 2**:

It can even unset a whole nested array, here's how you would do it (handling errors):

```
print_r($arr);
try {
    erase($arr, array('session', 'session3'));
}  catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
print_r($arr);
```

**Example 3**:

It also work with non-assiociative array:

```
$arr = array('fruit1', 'fruit2', 'fruit3');
print_r($arr);
try {
    erase($arr, array(0));
}  catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
print_r($arr);
```

**Example 4**:

In case of error:

```
$arr = array('fruit1', 'fruit2', 'fruit3');
print_r($arr);
try {
    erase($arr, array('pathThatDoesNotExit'));
}  catch (Exception $e) {
    // do what you got to do here in case of error (if the path you gave doesn't exist)!
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
print_r($arr);
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  It was my understanding (and I even coded an example that provided it) that doing an unset on a reference causes it to simply unlink the reference (not delete the item).  How does your code get around this?

Comment: @hendr1x By passing by reference you can, inside the function, unset an element of an array. However unset($theWholeArray) inside the function won't do work.

Answer (score 1):

If you'll always be passing in the key name of the array that contains the value, followed by the value, we can use [array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) to perform this.

```
if(false !== $key = array_search($value[1], $this->data[$value[0]])):
    unset($this->data[$value[0]][$key]);
endif;
```

Here's your [eval.in example](https://eval.in/197658)

Comment: Thank you for your help.  Unfortunately I need the erase method to be flexible to handle any number of dimensions/variables and values (including associative arrays) ( https://eval.in/197702 )

Comment: @hendr1x Okay, then how are you going to pass along arguments? Do you just want to search all arrays for a value then get it's key and unset it? Do you want to pass in the subarray? etc..

Comment: I am really flexible on how the system works.  Adam posted work code that took an array("level1","level2","level3").  If you want to discuss I'll keep checking.  Thanks for your help.